# How to display char array in TextBox of C#?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, performance, textbox

**Update:** It seems no to be garbage collection. But I still would like to know if or how I can reduce memory use by displaying a fixed-sized char array and not a very long string, where onyl the end is interesting for me.

---

In order to relieve my app from garbage collection (for better performance) I want to display a char array instead of a string in a multiline `TextBox` or other control. So I can modify the char array and make the control display it. I don't care for the first lines, they can be cut off.

It's kind of a **fast log viewer**.

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
// ...

// on every new line:
textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);
```

Right now I append string lines to the text box via `textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);` very frequently. I *(believe to)* notice garbage collection hit me every few seconds with a delay of almost 1 second because there is no other reason for my app to lag that often (most of my data is organized to avoid creating new objects).

**Edit:**

- I need to avoid creating objects no `new string(...)` so I can work with this 1 char array only.
- strings are immutable, so I can't edit those (char array or StringBuilder seem as the ways out)
- I also wish to reduce the memory use when I let it run for hours or even days.

Comment: How do you know the garbage collector hit you?

Comment: Why do you think that appending lines via a char array will help?  If you create a new string from your char array, you'll add a new string to the intern pool.  If you append character by character, you'll add *n* new strings to the string pool.  Garbage collection is almost certainly not your issue here, and it looks like you're trying to optimize something without having a clear idea as to what the causes of your performance are.

Comment: Some code would be good.

Comment: So from your edit about you *believing* GC is the reason I see that you're creating a problem when there really is none: Any application can "lag" as often as it pleases due to whatever happens in Windows. It's not a real-time OS, you know? We're creating services that handle hundreds of TCP commands per second and they don't lag - and I'm pretty sure that most people involved haven't ever spent a single thought on replacing strings by char arrays...

Comment: Have you tried a performance profiler? as others i suspect your real issue lays elsewhere. If you are editing your variable and updating it regularly why don't you take an ajax route?

Comment: Are you accessing the TextBox's `Text` property anywhere in your code?  If so, you may be causing the TextBox's entire content to be captured in a fresh `string` every time the text changes.  Presumably, those strings will become quite large.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That was what I was thinking. But no, this one textbox is only accessed via `Text.Length` and `AppendText()`.

Comment: @mini-me Accessing `Text.Length` requires accessing `Text`, which causes a string to be created internally if the content has changed since the last time you accessed `Text`.  Why do you need to access that property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work... the TextBox stores its text internally. When you set `Text`, or call `AppendText()`, etc., the control copies the data you give it to its internal string. There's no way to "point it" at a character array which you can update and have it see your changes.

To get this, you would need to write your own control which draws the text based on an array. (And this is in fact what most programs that display large amounts of text, such as text editors, do.)

However, are you certain you fully understand what is causing the performance issues you're seeing? You may be right, but garbage collection caused by allocating too many `string` objects would not be my first suspect. Have you run your code in a performance/memory profiler and investigated this thoroughly, or are you just guessing?

Comment: I guess you're right about writing own Control for that (if I have to). I'll except your answer since no one likes the question anyways.

Comment: @mini-me it's not that no one likes the question - it's that you're getting WAAAAY ahead of yourself.  For most cases, string interning and building text boxes are solved problems.  The issue is that you've already convinced yourself that you're having performance issues when you append strings to a textbox without having any concrete proof that it's the case.

Answer (score 1):

A `TextBox` uses a mutable text model internally, so appending text should not cause stop-the-world garbage collections.  While you may be generating new `string` instances for each line, they should be very short-lived, and therefore shouldn't (often) be promoted out of the ephemeral generation.  Collecting the ephemeral generation is cheap, and would not cause responsiveness issues.

I therefore suspect that you are inadvertently causing the `TextBox` to create a new `string` from its entire content every time you update it.  This would happen if you access its `Text` property anywhere in your update code, which from your comments above would seem to be the case.

Perhaps you are accessing `Text.Length` in order to scroll to the end, or something along those lines?  If so, try instead calling `TextBox.ScrollToEnd()` (WPF) or `TextBox.ScrollToCaret()` (Windows Forms) immediately after the call to `AppendText()`.

Comment: It's actually auto-scrolling. But after removing any `Text` use it makes no difference.

Comment: How is it auto-scrolling?

Comment: It's doing it on it's own. `Font, Dock, Multiline, ReadOnly, ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical, AppendText` are the only members used. I guess it automatically scrolls down when you append text.

Comment: Ah, so it does.  `AppendText()` internally updates the selection.